# Confirming symmetry about a curve/line?

Tags: graphing-functions, symmetry

I'm a bit confused, is symmetric about Origin same as symmetric about $y=x$ line?

Yes or no, how can I check for myself? I mean how can I do it on paper, let's take a random line/curve and

Comment: Symmetry around a *point* in the plane usually means rotational symmetry.  Symmetry across a *line* usually means reflectional symmetry.  If you take the graph of $y=\sin(x)$ on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and rotate it around the origin, you get the same graph (the function is odd).  But if you reflect it across $y=x$, you get the graph of the arcsine function.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks, so y=x reflection should be considered as a traditional way of geometrically imagining inverse functions. The rotation and reflection part really cleared it up! Shouldn't you be writing an answer though so I could close the question?

Comment: You're right, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symmetry around a *point* in the plane usually means rotational symmetry. Symmetry across a *line* usually means reflectional symmetry.  These are very different symmetries.

If you take the graph of $y=\sin(x)$ on $[−π/2,π/2]$ and rotate it around the origin, you get the same graph (the function is odd). But if you reflect it across $y=x$, you get the graph of the arcsine function.

[image: graph of $y=\sin x$]
[image: graph of $y=\arcsin x$]

It's no coincidence that the graph of the inverse of a function $f$ is the reflection of the graph of $f$ in the line $y=x$.  If you work out the algebra, the reflection of the point $(a,b)$ in $y=x$ is $(b,a)$.  That is, this reflection *switches the coordinates*.  When dealing with functions, the inverse to a function switches the roles of $x$ and $y$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to well understand your question, but I suppose that you intend a [reflection symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_symmetry) with line $y=x$ and a [point reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection) (or central symmetry) with center $(0,0)$.

If this is the case the figure that you find can be as this:

[image]

where you see that from the same point $C$  we find two different points $D$ ( symmetric with respect the line) and $E$ ( symmetric with respect the origin).